# Review and component check 2.0 Turbo FSI while out of car

Tags: engine, vw, audi

I've pulled the engine and DSG transmission from an Audi A3 Quattro. From the research I have done, it's an EA888 design - it is labelled as a CCZA which I believe is pretty much the same as as CCTA but less some US-specific smog control.

[image]

With the engine now easily accessible, I'm thinking about what to check/replace before it goes back in the car. There was nothing inherently wrong AFAIK other than the radiator/condenser being accident damaged when I purchased it. I don't really want to go crazy and open it up as I want the car back in driveable form soon, but I do want to do things that will improve driveability/reliability and to some extent performance. So I'm seeking suggestions, which I'll document here.

My current list is:

- air filter & engine oil/filter: oil is currently drained and simple to do once engine back in.
- DSG oil & filter: as above
- spark plugs: remove, inspect and replace
- coolant pump: these have a habit of failing. inspect for leaks
- turbo diverter valve: inspect for wear/damage

Comment: would be a good time to do the timing belt/chain while the engine is out.

Answer (score 1):

Simple tasks (could as easily be done in car):

- Oil and oil filter/air filter change
- DSG oil and filter change
- Spark plugs - remove, inspect and possibly change

Harder tasks (much easier to do with engine out)

- Coolant pump check for oil damage/leaks (replace if need be)
- Serpentine belt replace
- Timing chain tensioner inspect.

  There's a little inspection cover you can pop off -  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G65J1aEszyc
- Turbo diverter valve inspect - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NSjhH-z0lgc
- Carbon buildup on intake valves - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PS8riAae_bM

Answer (score -1):

On that motor a timing belt kit with rollers.   But you need oem parts only.   That can be tricky.  If it has that coolant flange you should do that also.  Is that the chain driven water pump also?